# simple python list problem

Tags: python

According to the docs:

```
list.append(x): Add an item to the end of the list
```

So, if I do:

```
list = []
list.append("banana")
print list[0] --> which is suppose to print the FIRST item of the list
> banana
```

So far so good, however if now I append another item:

```
list.append("apple")
print list[0]
```

> apple

Wasn't it suppose to append to the END of the list? How do I keep the order of the list when appending? How should I print the first and last items of the list -- in the order they were added to it?

Thanks

Comment: You shouldn't use the name `list` as a variable name.  However, you must be missing something in your question.  Append add's elements to the back of the list

Comment: Just out of curiosity, you're not actually using the variable name `list` in your code, correct? Big no-no

Comment: @S.Lott, my reasoning was to provide an alert to other users who could be trying to answer the question as I still needed 10 minutes to accept the answer.

Comment: Folks are going to answer anyway.  Even after you accept an answer.  Not to worry about them.  You got what you needed, that's what mattered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> l = []
>>> l.append('banana')
>>> print l[0]
banana
>>> l.append('apple')
>>> print l[0]
banana
>>> print l
['banana', 'apple']
```

Works fine for me, are you sure you aren't clearing the list anytime?

Comment: Ahn! You nailed it! It is recreating the list on a loop! Thanks, I was getting nuts with it.

Answer (score 1):

Works for me. You probably ought to pick a name other than `list`, since there's a built-in function called `list`.

```
>>> list = []
>>> lst = []
>>> lst.append("banana")
>>> print lst[0]
banana
>>> lst.append("apple")
>>> print lst[0]
banana
>>> print lst
['banana', 'apple']
```

Comment: it works even with "list" for me. BTW.. you can ommit the "print"

Comment: @Bastian: I know it works, but it's a bad idea. And I was trying to change as little as possible from the OP's example, but yes, `print` can be omitted.